# iOS Internationalize Plain Number

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization, nsnumberformatter

I'm very new to the process of internationalization, so hopefully the answers to these questions aren't stupidly obvious.

In my app, I have some user-facing numbers that have no qualifiers or separators (i.e. they don't represent currency, time, or anything else; they're just numbers. And, I want, for example, 1000 to display as 1000, not 1,000 or 1.000). My questions as as follows:

1. If I choose to use a NumberFormatter to internationalize these numbers, what changes (if any) might it make to the format to the resulting String based on the user's locale? For example, would a right-to-left locale reverse the order of the digits in a multi-digit number?
2. My app's functionality depends on the user seeing all numbers in base 10 and each number 0-9 being representable as a single character... would internationalizing the numbers invalidate these assumptions?

For the record, this is the only code I'm using to try to internationalize the numbers:

```
NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: number as NSNumber, number: .none)
```

Comment: In other words, you don't actually want the number to be internationalized, correct? Then don't use a number formatter.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if I want it to be internationalized; it depends on what the range of potential outputs for the number formatter is. For example, it's okay if the digits of the numbers are reversed for right-to-left languages (if it works that way) but it's not okay if the numbers are represented using characters other than 0-9. I guess what I'm asking is what the possible range of outputs for the number formatter are.

Comment: Try Arabic and see what you get.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of “,” and “.”? (These are controlled by the number formatter’s `.groupingSeparator` property, which can be set to the empty string.)

Comment: If you need exclusively Latin digits (and not Arabic/Sanskrit/etc. based on the locale), there are a variety of ways to format the string with or without `NumberFormatter`. The question is why you might want these to _not_ be localized.